# What is the generally preferred way to rank search results when search term includes delimiter

Tags: search, lucene, hibernate-search, information-retrieval

I have two documents `4349` and `P 43`.

A search string of `P 43` returns both in order

- `4349`
- `P 43`

My indexing def is like below

```
@AnalyzerDefs({
    @AnalyzerDef(
        name = "ngram",
        charFilters = {
            @CharFilterDef(factory = HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class)
        },
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class, params = {
                @Parameter(name = "words", value = "/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/english_stop.txt")}),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
                @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "15")
            })
        }
    ),
```

My search def is same without the ngramfilter and I have turned off lengthnorm.

Q: How to return the 2nd as a higher match or is the returned list ranking fine?

Q: Another way to phrase is how to take token order in input query into consideration or is already taken?

I was able to use  `querybuilder.phrase().withSlop(10)...sentence('P 43')` but now it doesnt return the first result anymore and only the second one

Comment: Little note: you defined `maxGramSize`, that might be a mistake? I opened https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2606 to improve feedback on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how your Analyzer definition will break up your terms.

Using such an *EdgeNGramFilterFactory* your *4349* will be converted in a sequence of tokens like this:

- `4349` -> [`4`, `43`, `434`, `4349`]

While "P 43" will be similarly split, but only after separating the "P" from the "43" as you also have a *StandardTokenizerFactory*:

- `P 43` -> [`p`, `4`, `43`]

So those tokens get inserted in your inverted index.

At query time, the sentence "P 43" will be split using the same approach:

- `P 43` -> [`p`, `4`, `43`]

Both your documents will contain all of `4` and `43`, like your query is asking for. So both documents match.

Now if you repeat the test but disable the N-Gram based filter we will have a different index:

- `4349` -> [`4349`]
- `P 43` -> [`p`, `43`]

Your query will be:

- `P 43` -> [`p`, `43`]

Only the second document matches any of the two terms `p` OR `43`, so only the second document will be considered a match.

I would suggest playing with the helper class **org.hibernate.search.util.AnalyzerUtils**, which is what I used myself to confirm which tokens are going to be produced for each input / analyzer configuration.

```
Analyzer analyzer = searchFactory.getAnalyzer( "ngram" );
System.out.println( AnalyzerUtils.tokenizedTermValues( analyzer, "description", "4349" ) );
System.out.println( AnalyzerUtils.tokenizedTermValues( analyzer, "description", "P 43" ) );
```